# How to prevent nose to check imported modules like matplotlib?

Tags: python, nose

I am using nose to my test python code. Each time I execute nosetests,
nose test also all imported modules like matplotlib, pandas, etc. .

This may take a while.

So how to skip imported modules explicitly?

Thanks in advance.

Example:

Code that should be tested:

```
import math
import matplotlib
import pandas

class myClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__a = 4


    def geta(self):
        return self.__a
```

And here comes the unittest-Code-Example:

```
import unittest


import myClass

class test_myClass( unittest.TestCase ):

    def setUp(self):
        self.aClass = myClass.myClass()

    def test_my_a(self):
        self.assertEqual(4, self.aClass.geta() )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you need is:

`--cover-package=your_python_package_name`

When you run your nose tests, you can supply either just one, or a list of these parameters to restrict nose to the listed packages of yours:

`nose --cover-package=one_package --cover-package=other_package`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for me. How to use it for a larger project in a clean way?